# Why do candlestick plots seem to show a cyclical structure?

Tags: random-variables, random-walk, data-analysis

One oddity I notice is that if a random or quasi-random data series such as price data is plotted, it is similar to a random walk, but if the same data series is plotted using candlesticks (open-close, high-low), there appears to be in many cases an undulating pattern.

I assume that this is caused by some kind of aliasing. Is there a mathematical explanation for it?